# having difficulties with class list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So, basically I have a class (new type) and I want to make a table of that specific type and fill it out with content but it seems that each column of the table if a duplicate of the last column. I think the problem is because of the declaration of the table itself.
This is the code please ignore the context of it it, just filling up the table with different stuff:

```
eng = {"hex":str(),"num":int(),"dec":str()}
def RempTab(n,t,np):
    f=open(np,"r")
    for i in range(n):

        t[i]["hex"] = f.readline()
       
        if i != n-1 :
            t[i]["hex"]=t[i]["hex"][0:len(t[i]["hex"])-1]
        t[i]["num"] = i+1
        t[i]["dec"] = convertDec(t[i]["hex"])
    f.close() 
t=[[eng] for i in range(n)]
RempTab(n,t,"hex.txt")
print(t)
```

Comment: Every element of `t` consists of `eng` - not a copy of `eng`, but the very same object each time.  If you want all of those objects to be independently modifiable, you would need to put `eng.copy()` into your list instead.

Comment: When I run your code I get: `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`.

Comment: yeah i removed some parts so the code looks short

Comment: it worked but is there any other solution with using .copy() ? i remember declaring it with for i in range just like a matrice

Comment: found it you put dict()

Comment: If you want all but the last character of `t[i]["hex"]` then you can use `t[i]["hex"][:-1]`. More generally, it might be a good idea if you included an example of the content of hex.txt and explain what you want the result to be here, because this code is fragile and there will probably be a much better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=[[eng] for i in range(n)]
```

The problem with your code is here, `eng` is an instance of `object`, that in Python works like this:

```
>>> class MyClass: pass
>>> my_object = MyClass()
>>> pointer = my_object # Now every change to my_object is also done to pointer
```

So what you are doing is filling this table (`t`) not with copies of `eng` but with `eng` itself.

---

To be more specific your `eng` is an instance of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which in Python is a built-in mutable type.

If you want to make a copy of a dict which is a different dict and doesn't depend on the first one, you should use the method `.copy`:

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> a["key"] = "value"
>>> a
{"key": "value"}
>>> b
{}
```

---

If you want your code to work as expected, this should be OK:

```
t = [[eng.copy()] for i in range(n)]
```